# html fade in subpage and change URL [UPDATE]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to load a new subpage in the background, change the URL and fade it in while an animation from the previous site is going on?

Here is [an example (jsFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/jHoover007/cogw8jxr/) of the animation, pretty simple:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';
    $('.r').on('click', function() {
        var preWidth = $('.l').width(),
            menuWidth = $('.r').width();
        $('.l').animate({
            left: '-' + preWidth
        }, 2000, 'easeOutQuad');
        $('.r').animate({
            left: menuWidth
        }, 2000, 'easeOutQuad', function() {
            $('.page').css({
                visibility: 'hidden'
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Its like a sliding door. It should work like this:

1. Press the right `div`.
2. The 2 `div`s slide to the sides.
3. In the background the new page is fading in while the slide animation  is going on.
4. The new page is fully visible and the URL changes.

I hope my explanation is easy to understand, hope you can help me out. Have a great day.

UPDATE:

First I had an issue with the back button in my browser. I wasn't able to load the first page "loader.html" with the animation, so I wrote an `if` query to check the state of a variable. Is there a better way of doing this.

`window.addEventListener('popstate', function(f){
        var bprsd = f.state;
        if(bprsd == null){
            bprsd = "loader.html";
        }
        if(bprsd = "loader.html" || " "){
            bprsd = null;
            location.reload();
        }
    });`

link to the test site [link](https://jhoover007.lima-city.de/loader.html)

Comment: I did a mistake with posting the link to the animation: https://jsfiddle.net/jHoover007/cogw8jxr/

Comment: Thanks for editing my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and No.

Yes it is possible but not with your structure. 
You need to load the other page using $.load:

```
var url="test.html";
$(document).on("click",function(){
  //todo fadeout
  $(document.body).load(url);
   location.pushState({},"MySite",url);
  //todo fadein
  });

url="newtest.html";
```

Comment: This works great for loading the html, but is there a way to also change the URL to the "newpage.html"?

Comment: Maybe I explained it wrong. The div should work like a link (changing the URL).

Comment: have a look at location.pushState

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked for me! I uploaded a test site onto a webspace. Integrated the `pushState()` function and added an eventlistener with popstate.